# How to store a base64 data to device internal/external storage in react-native?

Tags: base64, react-native

I want to convert the base64 data to the corresponding file(pdf,jpef,png etc) and save that converted file to device's local storage ie either internal/extenal storage in react-native. How to do that.

```
 <Image
      style={{
        height: "20%",
        width: "20%",
        resizeMode: "contain"
      }}
      source={{ uri: `data:gif;base64,${encodedData}` }}
    />
```

Here the encodedData is the base64 string. It's not necessary to display the file in the app itself. I've just testing the above code.

Comment: You could just save the uri in AsyncStorage even though you should probably save images on the server imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a library like rn-fetch-blob or react-native-fs for that purpose.

```
    import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

    const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;

//OUTSIDE YOUR COMPONENT

       // encodedData would be passed as an argument to the below function

    export function WriteBase64ToFile(Base64) { 
     let path = dirs.DCIMDir + "PATH/TO/FILE.png" 

     RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(path, Base64, 'base64')
     .then((result) => {console.log("File has been saved to:" + result))
     .catch(error => console.log(err);
        }

// THEN LATER INSIDE YOUR COMPONENT CALL THE FUNCTION

      WriteBase64ToFile(encodedData);
```

Do not forget to ask for Read and Write Permissions before doing this. For that purpose go to `.android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and add the following lines in your `<manifest>`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

reference: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#writefilepathstring-contentstring--array-encodingstringpromise

Comment: What do you mean by "PATH/TO/FILE" . In my case there is saved png file, I only have a base64 string which I needed to be converted to a file.

Comment: "PATH/TO/FILE"  means the path where you want to save your converted base64 to .png file to. e.g  `let path = dirs.DCIMDir + "/Images/image.png"`

Answer (score 1):

use RNFetchBlob

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';


var Base64Code = base64Image.split("data:image/png;base64,"); //base64Image is my image base64 string

const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;

var path = dirs.DCIMDir + "/image.png";

RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(path, Base64Code[1], 'base64')
.then((res) => {console.log("File : ", res)});
```

or this library for storing image [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)

Comment: this is not working, when I console log var value = RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(path, Base64Code[1], "base64"); I'm getting this as response 
{ _40: 0,
      _65: 2,
      _55: 
       { [Error: Expected "data" is a String when encoding is "utf8" or "base64", however got undefined]
         line: 115671,
         column: 68,
         sourceURL: 'http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false' },
      _72: null,
      _51: 0 },

Comment: if you're getting undefined then your split function is not working as expected.